# Phalcon PHP: Select option value POST in table using DataTable

Tags: javascript, mysql, phalcon

I have a problem in getting the value in my  field, I am using DataTable for my table.

My error is , the selected value is not posting in table.

here's my code...
NOTE: I'm using Phalocon PHP , DataTable API for phalcon.

here's my controller :

```
public function orderWalkinAction() 
{
    $this->view->disable();
    if($this->request->isPost()) {
        $arr = array();
        $dropdown_id = $this->request->getPost('dropdown_id', 'striptags');
        $select_orderitems_query = Medics::find(
            [
                "conditions" => "medID = :id: AND status = 'ACTIVE'",
                "bind" => 
                [ 
                    "id" => $dropdown_id,
                ]
            ]
        );
            foreach ($select_orderitems_query as $data_orderItem) {
                $orderitem_medID        = $data_orderItem->medID;
                $orderitem_code         = $data_orderItem->itemcode;
                $orderitem_name         = $data_orderItem->itemname;
                $orderitem_brand        = $data_orderItem->itembrand;
                $orderitem_quan         = $data_orderItem->itemquan;
                $orderitem_price        = $data_orderItem->itemprice;
                $orderitem_totalprice   = $data_orderItem->totalPrice; 

                $arr[] = array(
                    "itemcode"  => $orderitem_code,
                    "itemname"  => $orderitem_name."-".$orderitem_brand,
                    "itemquan"  => $orderitem_quan,
                    "itemprice" => $orderitem_price,
                    "total"     => $orderitem_totalprice,
                    "action"    => "<button class='btn btn-danger' id='orderRecord-delete' data-id='".$orderitem_medID."'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>"
                ); 
            }

        $dataTables = new DataTable();
        $dataTables->fromArray($arr)->sendResponse();
    }


}
```

Here's my Js

```
$(document).on('change', '#items', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dropdown_val = $(this).val();
    if(dropdown_val != null) 
    {
        //Table For Order Items
        $('#order_tbl').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            deferRender: true,
            ajax: {
                        url: '/HPsys/walkin/orderWalkin',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: { dropdown_id : dropdown_val }
                    },
            columns: [
                { data : "itemcode" },
                { data : "itemname" },
                { data : "itemquan" },
                { data : "itemprice" },
                { data : "total" },
                { data : "action" },
            ]
        });
    } 
    else 
    {

    }
});
```

Here's my View

```
<select class="form-control" id="items">
                <option value="">-- Select Item --</option>
            </select>
            <hr>
            <h2 class="text-center">Order Details </h2>
            <table class="table" id="order_tbl">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

            </table>
```

If there's a vlog/tutorial/ or any recommendation please feel free to comment, I really appreciate that.

Comment: @Phil yeah sure, my bad.

Comment: What debugging have you done? I'd start by looking in the browser's _Network_ console... inspect the AJAX request and check what data its sending? FYI, you have no useful `<option>` elements in your `<select>` so I'm not sure what sort of value you expect

Comment: @Phil in my `<option>` I append the dropdown using javascript , then what I am expecting is when I select one of the value in my `<select>` it will appear in my DataTable

Comment: So, about that _Network_ console...

Comment: @Phil what about console network? it show error by POST, then show the ID of the selected value which is correct, but no data show in the dataTable

Comment: What is _"error by POST"_?

Comment: @Phil 500 interval error. I think in my controller(back end) that error . but I really don't understand what's wrong or missing in my controller to run it successfully

Comment: Check your web-server's error log. The reason for the 500 error will be in there

Comment: @Phil sorry for the late reply, where can I find the web-server error log? I just use to configure the error is the programmer console log. (F12)

Comment: How are you running the PHP site? Apache, NGINX, `php -S`? Whatever you're using will have logs.

Comment: @Phil I use apache, then call in browser then I check console log or network->XHR then there's the error but in my case the error is POST 500 interval error. Where I can find that web-server's error log?

Comment: [Where are Apache file access logs stored?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored)

Comment: @Phil Thank you I really appreciate your help, I already Solved my problem :) Thanks a lot. Cheers!

Comment: If it's worth doing, please answer your own question below. There's nothing worse than searching and finding your exact problem and seeing no answer but a _"it's ok, I fixed it"_ comment

Comment: @Phil ohh.. sorry my bad, my error only is the url of the API i used in dataTable for phalcon. I just review the documentation of that API then I get to that. that's it.